# Firefox - Make the New Tab page always have the textured gray background

Tags: firefox

Firefox 13.0 introduced a [Most Visited Pages](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/13.0/releasenotes/) function to the New Tab page. Now, instead of a blank page, you can choose to be presented with a grid layout of your most visited pages.

[image: most visited]

One thing I like about this layout is the soft gray pattern used as the background. How can I apply this 'look' to the blank New Tab page as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying the following CSS using [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) or [userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.css) will style the **blank** New Tab page appropriately!

```
window#newtab-window div#newtab-scrollbox[page-disabled="true"]
{
    background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229) !important;
    background-image: url("chrome://browser/skin/newtab/noise.png"),
                      -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5),
                      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)) !important;
    background-attachment: fixed !important;
}
```

---

**Before:**

[image: before]

**After:**

[image: after]

---

### Bonus

Since the default browser background color is **white**, there may be a momentary flash when you open a new tab. To minimize this effect, you can set the `browser.display.background_color` preference in `about:config` to `#eef0ec`. Restart Firefox for this change to take effect.

> **Note:** This color was chosen based on averaging the Most Visited page's background to a palette of two colors. Feel free to suggest a color which minimizes the flash even further.